# In what form is optical flow used an input to a neural network?

Tags: computer-vision

I have extracted the optical flow of images. Should I pass the x,y optical flow or should I pass the RGB visualization as the input. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: what is the "RGB visualization"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass in the optical flow field, and not a visualization of that field. The difference is that one is the optical flow, and the other is an arbitrary function of the flow $f: \mathbb R^{H \times W \times 2} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{H \times W \times 3}$.

Unless you have reason to believe that the visualization extracts useful features from the optical flow which cannot be easily extracted from just the flow field itself, it's highly advisable not to use the visualization.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please check the (d) and (e) images. That is what I mean by RGB visualization.

Comment: @user239457 i checked it out. it doesn't change my answer